# Arrays: same line of code printing different answers?

Tags: c, arrays

I have just started learning C and I have encountered the following problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define T 1
int G;

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5] = {7,8,9,10,11};
    int a;

    printf("%d\n", G);
    printf("%d\n", arr[T]);
    printf("%d\n", arr[G]);

    a = arr[T]*arr[G];

    printf("%d\n",a);


    printf("%c", arr[T]*arr[G]); //why is this answer printed differently from a?

    return 0;
}
```

Appreciate your kind help!

Comment: Do you know the difference between `%d` and `%c`?

Comment: If you use %c, c prints the corresponding ASCII key for the integer value. So in your case it's returning ASCII value of 56 (arr[1]*arr[0] i.e.7*8).

Comment: Why doesn't `G` have any value? This is *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're printing it as a character with "%c".

Try these:

```
printf("%d", 65);
printf("%c", 65);
```

And then look at the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/). 
And then read up on [printf Format String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string).
All the best.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you so much! May i ask why does %c return 8?

Comment: Look at the ascii table. The number 56 (which is the product) corresponds to the character '8'.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are using G before assigning a value to it, it could print anything.  Also your formats are different.